# I am trying to read a utf-8 file in python and keep BOM, but BOM is automatically deleted when i do file.read

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have done the following:

```
a = open(text, encoding='utf-8').read
```

I am trying to count the words in this text file and include the BOM.

However, when I use `readline`, the BOM is not deleted.

Does anyone know how to keep the BOM with `read` not `readlines`?

Comment: Same. Both `read()` and `readlines()` keep the BOM.

Answer (score -1):

Hello I try this and work:

```
a = open('text.txt',encoding='utf-8').read()
print(a)
```